# finding double integral bounded by domain

Tags: calculus, integration, geometry, derivatives, multiple-integral

question : 
find the value of $\iint_D \frac{x}{(x^2 + y^2)}dxdy$ ,

 domain : $0\le x \le 1, x^2 \le y \le x$ 
,
so here, i tried to draw it first and i got that the domain is region in first quadrant bounded by $y=x^2$ and $y=x$ and i decided to convert the equation to polar coordinate,

\begin{align}
\int_{0}^{\pi/2}\int_{(r^2cos^2\theta)}^{rcos \theta}cos \theta   dr d\theta\\
\end{align}
is this true?

i proceed to solve the integral, but still got r in the last equation. the answer of the book said $\frac{1}{2} log 2$
thankyou

Comment: why do you need polar coordinate?

Comment: @GuyFsone because i think it is easier to solve using polar coordinate $\iint_D \frac{x}{(x^2 + y^2)}dxdy$ much simpler(?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\iint_D \frac{x}{(x^2 + y^2)}dxdy$$ ,

domain : $0\le x \le 1, x^2 \le y \le x$ is equivalent to 
implies $0\le y \le 1,$ $y \le x \le \sqrt{y} $ and
$$\frac{\partial}{\partial x}\ln(x^2+y^2)=  \frac{2x}{(x^2 + y^2)}$$

Therefore,

$$I=\iint_D \frac{x}{(x^2 + y^2)}dxdy  = \int_{0}^{1}\int_{y}^{\sqrt{y}}\frac{x}{(x^2 + y^2)}dxdy = \int_{0}^{1}\frac{1}{2}[\ln((x^2 + y^2)]_y^{\sqrt{y}}dy =\int_{0}^{1}\ln(y+y^2)-\ln(2y^2)dy $$ ,

But $(x\ln x-x)' = \ln x$ and $$\ln(y+y^2)-\ln(2y^2) = -\ln y+\ln(1+y) -\ln2$$
Hence 
$$I= \frac{1}{2}\int_{0}^{1}\ln(y+y^2)-\ln(2y^2)dy =[(1+y)\ln(1+y)-(1+y) -y\ln y+y -y\ln 2 ]_0^1 = \frac{1}{2}\ln 2$$

Comment: thankyou so much for the clear explanation! if i dont changed the domain like you did the integration wlll be much harder.but i still wondering if i can use polar coordinate or not to solve this problem.

Comment: what tried with polar coordiantes is not correct. first how did you find the angle can very up to $\pi/2$? and the second integration does not make any sense. I think polar coordinate are suite for this problem.

Comment: thankyou for the feedback, for second integration i just substituted $rcos \theta$ to $ x^2 \le y \le x$ and for $\pi/2 $ i got it since the figure is in first quadrant , so it is $0->\pi/2$ ? is this true?

Comment: i think i got it wrong, for the oute integral it is supposed to be $\theta = \pi/4$ and the r maybe $\sqrt 2 \le r \le \sqrt 2$, which one is true?